# In Agricola, do family members occupy as many rooms as possible?

Tags: agricola

Say I have three rooms and two family members, and I take a "family growth (even without space)" action (for example using the Lover occupation). Does the new family member now occupy my third room, or double up with one of the existing family members? In other words, can I now immediately take a standard "family growth" action, or will I now need to build an extra room?

[Note that if I'd done it the other way around ("growth", then "growth without space"), I could definitely have four people in my three rooms.]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The third member will occupy the third room of your house, even if you use the "Family Growth even without a room" action.**

The relevant rule starts on page 9 of the [rule book](http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/agricola_eng.pdf), under "Family Growth even without a room":

> Note: If a player who uses this card later extends her home, she may not use the other Family Growth card again until she has more rooms than Family members: the new rooms must first be used for Family members that did not previously have their own rooms.

This means you cannot take the actions in the order you are suggesting without building an additional room between the two "Family Growth" actions.